# Azure DevOps bash script not seeing binaries on PATH

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to execute a Bash script in my build pipeline that is run on a self-hosted agent. The error I am encountering is:

```
##[section]Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.148.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613738)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
[command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe --noprofile --norc -c pwd
/mnt/c/agent/_work/1/s/utilities/Uncrustify
Formatted command: . '/mnt/c/agent/_work/1/s/utilities/Uncrustify/check.sh'
[command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe --noprofile --norc -c pwd
/mnt/c/agent/_work/_temp
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe --noprofile --norc /mnt/c/agent/_work/_temp/146cb6ce-a7e9-48f6-b4f9-6cde2bf22685.sh
/mnt/c/agent/_work/1/s/utilities/Uncrustify/check.sh: line 27: uncrustify: command not found
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
##[section]Finishing: Bash
```

The `check.sh` script simply runs uncrustify:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Absolute path to this script, e.g. /home/user/bin/foo.sh
SCRIPT="$0"

# Absolute path this script is in, e.g. /home/user/bin/
SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname -- "$SCRIPT")"

# Relative path from this script to the top level of this repo.
GITREPO="$SCRIPTPATH/../.."

uncrustify --check -c "$GITREPO/.uncrustify.cfg" \
    $(find "$GITREPO" -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.hxx")
```

The bash task in `azure-pipelines.yml` is:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: 'utilities/Uncrustify/check.sh'
    displayName: 'Verify coding standard compliance'
    failOnStderr: true
```

I have verified that `uncrustify.exe` exists on the PATH, which happens to be in `/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I need to do something special to allow a bash script to call other executables that may be on the PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about an hour of trial and error, the fix was to explicitly specify the extension in the shell script.

```
uncrustify --check -c "$GITREPO/.uncrustify.cfg" \
    $(find "$GITREPO" -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.hxx")
```

became:

```
uncrustify.exe --check -c "$GITREPO/.uncrustify.cfg" \
    $(find "$GITREPO" -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.hxx")
```

Such a minor thing. This isn't a problem when actually executing it manually on any of my setups.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I had to wait 2 days before I could.